# OOP PYTHON: Using cls() to create multiple constructor without calling __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instantiation

I have a Python class which takes an url in parameter and launches a crawler on a news website.

Once the creation of the object is finished, the object is stored in a Elasticsearch cluster.

I want to create a method that takes in input the Elasticsearch document, and creates an object from it.

```
class NewsArticle():

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        # Launch a crawler and fill in the other fields like author, date, ect ...

    @classmethod
    def from_elasticsearch(cls, elasticsearch_article):
        document = elasticsearch_article['_source']
        obj = cls(document['url'])
        obj.url = document['url']
        obj.author = document['author']
        .
        .
        .
```

The problem is, when I'm calling...

```
# response is my document from elasticsearch
res = NewsArticle.from_elasticsearch(response)
```

...the method `__init__` will be called and will launch my crawler. Is there anyway that it doesn't launch my crawler or call the init method?

Comment: So you want to create an object without initializing an object?

Comment: Maybe you should not have that crawler stuff in your `__init__`.

Comment: @StevenSummers I would like two know if I can have 2 differents constructors

Comment: No, `python` doesn't support overloading methods. It does however let you provide optional arguments and you can pass a flag (`bool`) to determine other actions. Or use other methods to set values. Or as khelwood mentioned, re-structure your code so it runs when you call it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple `if` and a default parameter `crawl`:

```
class NewsArticle():

    def __init__(self, url, crawl=True):
        self.url = url
        if crawl:
            # Launch a crawler and fill in the other fields like author, date, ect ...

    @classmethod
    def from_elasticsearch(cls, elasticsearch_article):
        document = elasticsearch_article['_source']
        obj = cls(document['url'], crawl=False)
        obj.url = document['url']
        obj.author = document['author']
```

Comment: I did what you say and I also took my crawler out of the init in a class method called from_crawled. The if statement will call from_crawled or from_elasticsearch depending of the argument in the init. Is that a good architecture? Should I use @classmethod?

Comment: Sounds good to me. The use of class method also looks reasonable.

Comment: Which do you recommend: using my init method only to define the type of my attributes and using class method to create my objects or putting a if statement in my init, adding the methodology and the response from Elasticsearch as parameters?

Comment: I would allow to make fully working instance without the need of a class method. So an if in `__init__` seems fine.